# \subfigure doesn't generate space between words

Tags: subfig

could anyone tell me why the subfigure can't generate space between the words, they are all linked together?

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \subfigure[\label{fig:beamFRFdr(a)}$Original  stiffness  distribtution$]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight]{Kdr.eps}}
  \subfigure[\label{fig:beamFRFdr(b)}$Corresponding  FRF $]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight]{FRFdr.eps}}
  \caption{\label{fig:beamFRFdr} degradation  Distribution  Identified  by  Original  Algorithm  and the  Corresponding  FRF. }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Dollar signs switch to math mode, so `$Original  stiffness  distribution$` is interpreted as a math formula, hence the missing spaces. Remove the `$`.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to present code, which we can copy and compile. Please test it yourself, your snippet won't compile. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the comment above: in math mode words are treated as series of variables. If you use `$\text{sentence}$`  the words in the *sentence* are set as an ordinary words and spaces. But why are you setting the subcaptions in math mode anyway? They don't contain math ..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: I disagree with closing question. Comments doesn't complete solve OP problems. As (s)he is novice on site, (s)he probably is not aware with other possible issues of provided code fragment.

Comment: I was stupid, just copied the template from others and did not figure out the all functions, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you after the following (but I may be wrong):

[image]

- From code fragment can be concluded, that you use obsolete package `subfigure`.
- Instead of it rather use `subfig` or even better `subcaption` package. - Both packages define `subfloat` environment with similar functionality as has `subfigure`.
- If you like to have italic shape of subcaption text, accordingly define this at package. Using math environment for this is wrong.
- For more possibilities to formating caption and subcaptions, please consult `caption` (and `su8bcaption`) package documentations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[text font=it]{subcaption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight}
\subfloat[Original stiffness  distribution  \label{fig:beamFRFdr}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\hfil
\subfloat[Corresponding  FRF   \label{fig:beamFRFdr}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Degradation  Distribution  Identified  by  Original  Algorithm  and the  Corresponding  FRF.}
\label{fig:beamFRFdr} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, for so a careful and detailed explanation, how to close this question?

Comment: @CuteQi, simple: just accept my answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer)    :-)